# Ruby regex how to exclude hit with quotes

Tags: ruby, regex

I face new challenge how to select only single word **PATIENT** from my sample string, so I need ignore if it's literal in single quotes and single sweep if possible. It also need to be word only and it solved already with `\b` switch. Tried pretty much all I could on [rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com).  do you think it's doable. Best.M

```
s = 'alpha \'patient\' #1 literal  PATIENT  and As  patieNT and patientXX '
regex=/\bpatient\b/i

regex =/(?<!['"])\bpatient\b(?!['"])/  ##!!!!  solved (c)  emsimpson92  

puts s.scan(regex)    # select only PATIENT only without qoutes
```

**Updated:** I use heat of the moment to solve another case how skip case when regex word preceded by `As` (but with 1+ spaces), how I can add `1 ore more space` condition into my first part, I tried `\s+` but it doesn't work here:
  `(?<!as\s) (?<!['"])\bpatient\b`  ## `AS with 1+ spaces

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you what you're looking for. `(?<!['"])patient(?!['"])`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SaEHzi/1)

Comment: Tx much emS!!!   works perfectly and with \b as well (?<!['"])\bpatient\b(?!['"]).  I never see ? in regex manuals. Sorry can't give your 10 stars,I'm not qualified yet!!!

Comment: `(?<!somepattern)` means your desired result is not preceded by "somepattern" and `(?!somepattern)` means your desired result is not followed by "somepattern". They're called negative lookaheads/lookbehinds

Comment: Tx again!!!   Really super!!!  Glad somebody already gave you +1 score.

Comment: “I never see ? in regex manuals.”—it’s literally impossible to find the regex manual consisting of at least 100 words that does not mention `?`. Also, if the answer helped, you **are supposed** to mark it as correct with a greeny check under the score.

Comment: Tx again all, I did more testing and realized that you can't use range `{1,}` inside of lookahead, this always give an error  `(?<!as[ ]{2,})`

Comment: @Mich28 you can use that sort of thing within a lookahead, but lookbehinds need to have fixed lengths, so you can't use any sort of `*`, `+` or `{x,}`, `?` etc

Comment: If you need a solution for that scenario, remove the lookbehind and use this: `(?:[^'"]|^)(patient)(?!['"])`. The full match will include the character before the quote, but you can retrieve the information you need out of the first capture group.